# I'm trying to create a script to send message "hello" to file name Hello in home directory

Tags: shell-script

And display the contents of the file in the stdout using `#!/bin/bash`

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo"hello" >> ~/Hello 
cat ~/Hello
```

should I use `tee ~/Hello` to display contents of file Hello in stdout ?

Comment: That's great! So, what is your question? What part of this is giving you trouble? Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: #!/bin/bash    echo"hello" >> ~/Hello   cat ~/Hello  but should I use tee ~/Hello to display contents of file Hello in stdout

Comment: @jackotonye What part of the word edit did you not understand. You should improve you post, not comment on comments.

Comment: You really a cruel person

Answer (score 1):

No, `tee` is not for displaying the contents of a file. As with most *nix commands, you can see its manual by running `man tee`. There, you will see:

```
NAME
   tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files

DESCRIPTION
   Copy standard input to each FILE, and also to standard output.
```

So, `tee` is used to write to files. The most common usage is to display text on screen and also save it to a file. For example:

```
echo "foo" | tee ~/bar
```

The command above will print `foo` to your screen (standard output) and also save it to the file `~/bar`.

If you want to show the contents of a file, the standard way is precisely what you're doing: `cat file`. So, `cat ~/Hello` will show the contents of the file `~/Hello`.

By the way, you have a typo in your script. You want `echo "hello"` not `echo"hello"`.